# Python 3.5.2 TypeError:' int ' object is not callable

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When module openpyxl was imported, I want to get the highest row. Then it turned out to be an Error.

[image]

Comment: Please add the stack trace over here as the plain text, instead of image link

Answer (score 3):

The error speaks for itself, `max_row` is not callable.

```
# do This
print (sheet.max_row)

# instead of
print (sheet.max_row())
```

Comment: print ( sheet.max_row)    is ok. Thanks.